# Get product version of DLLs

Tags: asp.net, reflection

Trying to get the "Product Version" attribute from loaded DLLs.

For example, my System.Web.dll has a product version of 2.0.50727.4955 if you click File > Properties from explorer.

However I have the following code:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    stringBuilder.Append("<br/>");
    stringBuilder.Append("<div><b>Name: </b>" + assembly.GetName() + "</div>");
    stringBuilder.Append("<div><b>Full name: </b>" + assembly.FullName + "</div>");
    stringBuilder.Append("<div><b>Is from GAC: </b>" + assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache + "</div>");
    stringBuilder.Append("<div><b>ImageRuntimeVersion: </b>" + assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion + "</div>");
}
```

The ImageRuntimeVersion returns v2.0.50727, is there any way I can get the last 4 digits of the product version also?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I usually do something like this, which does return the last portion of the version:

```
return Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Web.UI.ScriptManager)).GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Allara, I did try the revision property however this returned 2.0.0.0

Comment: This is incorrect, it returns only the assembly version, not the file or product version.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`FileVersionInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx):

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(string).Assembly.Location)
```

Comment: If I'm iterating through the assemblies dynamically, the location is not available. For example if I put  FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location) in my foreach loop, it throws an exception: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

Comment: @timothy: You'll need to skip those.  They don't have files at all, so the information you're looking for does not exist.  Check the `IsDynamic` property